# Error 404 NotFound After Installing Nexus Repository Manager On Windows Server 2016

Tags: maven, repository, nexus, sonatype

I install nexus repository manager (v 3.20.0-04) on windows server 2016

After that i run this command in cmd (on bin folder)

```
nexus.exe \run
```

Now i open http://localhost:8081 on browser and see just this page

[image]

how can resolve this problem?

**SOLVED**

I restart server and my problem solved.

Comment: Do you have artifactory as your context path (see https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Configuring+the+Runtime+Environment#ConfiguringtheRuntimeEnvironment-ChangingtheContextPath) ?

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache... guessing you had artifactory installed earlier?

Comment: that's right. i installed jfrog repository oss, and after clear cache, it is work correctly. thanks (please add as answer to set as correct answer)

Comment: @rseddon perfect guess! That just happened to me

Answer (score 0):

Just open cmd as an adminstrative mode

set yout path `cd C:\Program Files\nexus-3.20.1-01\bin`

then type `nexus.exe /run`

It will be run.